# Ассоциативный массив

Tags: массивы, php

Всем привет. Есть, к примеру, такой массив:

```
<?php
$arr_assoc["Галина"] = "Петро";
$arr_assoc["Катерина"] = "Роман";
$arr_assoc["Дарина"] = "Микола";
$arr_assoc["Олена"] = "Александр";
$arr_assoc["Мария"] = "Андрей";
?>
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы массив перемешивался, имена девушек оставались на месте, а парни менялись, и чтобы если парень попал к той же девушке, что была раньше, процесс запускался ещё раз до тех пор, пока не будет у каждой новый парень?

Comment: Забавная секс-игрушка получится...)

Comment: Да нет, вы не то подумали - это для моего сайта знакомств.

Comment: Все имена парней уникальные?

Comment: Да уникальные.

Answer (score 2):

Изобрел такой костыль:

```
   $arr_assoc = array();
    $arr_assoc["Галина"] = "Петро";
    $arr_assoc["Катерина"] = "Роман";
    $arr_assoc["Дарина"] = "Микола";
    $arr_assoc["Олена"] = "Александр";
    $arr_assoc["Мария"] = "Андрей";

$m = array_values($arr_assoc);
$w = array_keys($arr_assoc);
$new_assoc = array();   
do {
    shuffle($m);
    shuffle($w);
    $new_assoc = array_combine($w, $m);
} while (count(array_intersect_assoc($new_assoc, $arr_assoc)) != 0);

print_r($new_assoc);
/* Результат
Array ( [Дарина] => Петро [Мария] => Роман [Олена] => Микола [Катерина] => Александр [Галина] => Андрей )
*/
```

Но я бы это использовать не стал - Вам стоит пересмотреть алгоритм.

Comment: Прям как играть в "камень-ножницы-бумага" вдесятером ;-)

Comment: Взять список всех перестановок, исключить имеющих пересечения с исходными массивом и случайным образом выбрать результат. Но, поскольку речь идёт о php, данный вариант кажется бредовым. Чуть больше пар -- и результата можно не долждаться.

(Кстати, проверка на пересечение тривиальна, если переставлять индексы от 1 до n или от 0 до n-1: смотри, нет ли на месте i значения i)

Comment: Ваш алгоритм на самом деле не так плох, как кажется: он короткий, прозрачный и легко понимаем.  
Но излишне перемешивать и ключи и значения, делайте что-то одно.  
Шансы на то, что цикл сработает 2 раза: 1 из 6, что 3 раза: 1 из 36 итд. В наше время такие потери производительности не существенны.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr_assoc["Галина"] = "Петро";
$arr_assoc["Катерина"] = "Роман";
$arr_assoc["Дарина"] = "Микола";
$arr_assoc["Олена"] = "Александр";
$arr_assoc["Мария"] = "Андрей";

$m = array_values($arr_assoc);
$w = array_keys($arr_assoc);

$size = sizeof($w);

for($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $new_assoc[$w[$i]] =  $m[($size == $i+1) ? 0 : ($i+1)]; 
}

var_dump($new_assoc);
```

Comment: Рандома нет. Обычная последовательная групповуха.

Comment: @Равнодушный - так автору и не требовалось рандомно мешать, он ведь вообще не указал как :-)

Answer (score 1):

Вот моя попытка:

```
$arr_assoc["Галина"] = "Петро";
$arr_assoc["Катерина"] = "Роман";
$arr_assoc["Дарина"] = "Микола";
$arr_assoc["Олена"] = "Александр";
$arr_assoc["Мария"] = "Андрей";
echo var_dump($arr_assoc);

$m = array_values($arr_assoc);
$w = array_keys($arr_assoc);
while(true) {
    $res = array();
    $m1 = $m;
    for($i=0; $i < count($w) - 1; $i++) {
        $herboy = $arr_assoc[$w[$i]]; 
        $herboy1 = "";
        /* убираем её боя, если его кто-то ещё не увёл */
        /* лучше заменить на array_search */
        for($j = 0; $j < count($m1); $j++)
            if ($m1[$j] == $herboy) {
                unset($m1[$j]);
                $m1 = array_values($m1);
                $herboy1 = $herboy;
                break;
            }
        $k = rand(0, count($m1) - 1);
        $res[$w[$i]] = $m1[$k];
        unset($m1[$k]);
        if($herboy1 != "") array_push($m1, $herboy1);
        $m1 = array_values($m1);
    }
    /* Не остался ли последней девушке надоевший ей бойфренд */
    if($arr_assoc[$w[$i]] != $m1[0]) {
        $res[$w[$i]] = $m1[0];
        break;
    }
}
echo var_dump($res);
```